# unix sed and while loop

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I'm trying to create a design document from informatica XML as input.
Here I have taken the list of transformations used and kept them in a separate file (LOTO.txt)
and the master XML file (testingfull.txt)
I am taking the 1st value from the first column and checking what kind of transformation it is and continuing the code. My issue is for LKP's it is returning same SELECT query for all the LKP's. My code is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read T
do
{
    TYPE=`echo $T |cut -c-4|cut -c2-`
    ##echo "$TYPE"
    ##TT=`echo \'$T\'`
    ##echo "$TT"
    if [ "$TYPE" = "SQ_" ];  then
        SQL=`cat testingfull.txt|sed -n '/$T/,/VALUE ="Never"/p'|grep "Sql Query" | sed -n '/SELECT/,/"/p' | sed  's/&#xD;&#xA;//g'| sed 's/&apos;Y&apos;//g' | cut -d'"' -f4`
        echo "$T     : $SQL"$'\n'>>singletesting.txt

    elif [ "$TYPE" = "GET" ];  then
        SQL='GET_MAX_VALUE               :           Reusable transformation to get the max key value from the target Table'
        echo "$SQL"$'\n'>>singletesting.txt
    elif [ "$TYPE" = "Lkp" ];  then
        SQL=`cat testingfull.txt|sed -n '/$T/,/VALUE ="Null Is Highest Value"/p'|grep "Lookup Sql Override" | sed -n '/SELECT/,/"/p' | sed  's/&#xD;&#xA;//g'| sed 's/&apos;Y&apos;//g' | cut -d'"' -f4`
        echo "$T     : $SQL"$'\n'>>singletesting.txt
    else
        echo "$T           :   under construnction"$'\n'$'\n'>>singletesting.txt
    fi
}
done <LOTO.txt
```

LOTO.txt:

```
"Lkp_CDL_BOOKINGS_F_Delta_AMT"
"Lkp_CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO"
"Lkp_EQIP_MAINT_PCT"
"SQ_CDL_PURCHASE_ORDER_F"
```

Below is the main XML file:

```
<TRANSFORMATION DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="Lkp_CDL_BOOKINGS_F_Delta_AMT" OBJECTVERSION ="1" REUSABLE ="NO" TYPE ="Lookup Procedure" VERSIONNUMBER ="4">
    <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="decimal" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="BOOKINGS_FACT_KEY" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="LOOKUP/OUTPUT" PRECISION ="38" SCALE ="0"/>
    <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="decimal" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="PURCHASE_ORDER_KEY" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="LOOKUP" PRECISION ="38" SCALE ="0"/>
    <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="decimal" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="BOOK_DATE_KEY" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="LOOKUP/OUTPUT" PRECISION ="38" SCALE ="0"/>
    <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="decimal" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="HARDWARE_CISCO_LC_AMT" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="LOOKUP/OUTPUT" PRECISION ="26" SCALE ="7"/>
    <!-- ="0"/> -->
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup Sql Override" VALUE ="SELECT &#xD;&#xA;CDL_BOOKINGS_F.BOOKINGS_FACT_KEY as BOOKINGS_FACT_KEY,&#xD;&#xA;CDL_BOOKINGS_F.PURCHASE_ORDER_KEY as PURCHASE_ORDER_KEY,&#xD;&#xA;CDL_BOOKINGS_F.BOOK_DATE_KEY as BOOK_DATE_KEY,&#xD;&#xA;CDL_BOOKINGS_F.HARDWARE_CISCO_LC_AMT as HARDWARE_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.HARDWARE_CISCO_USD_AMT as HARDWARE_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.HARDWARE_NON_CISCO_LC_AMT as HARDWARE_NON_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.HARDWARE_NON_CISCO_USD_AMT as HARDWARE_NON_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.SOFTWARE_ESSNTL_CISCO_LC_AMT as SOFTWARE_ESSNTL_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.SOFTWARE_ESSNTL_CISCO_USD_AMT as SOFTWARE_ESSNTL_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.FREIGHT_CISCO_LC_AMT as FREIGHT_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.FREIGHT_CISCO_USD_AMT as FREIGHT_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.FREIGHT_NON_CISCO_LC_AMT as FREIGHT_NON_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.FREIGHT_NON_CISCO_USD_AMT as FREIGHT_NON_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.INSTALLATION_CISCO_LC_AMT as INSTALLATION_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.INSTALLATION_CISCO_USD_AMT as INSTALLATION_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.INSTALLATION_NON_CISCO_LC_AMT as INSTALLATION_NON_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.INSTALLATION_NON_CISCO_USD_AMT as INSTALLATION_NON_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.CONSULTING_CISCO_LC_AMT as CONSULTING_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.CONSULTING_CISCO_USD_AMT as CONSULTING_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.FINANCED_TAX_CISCO_LC_AMT as FINANCED_TAX_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.FINANCED_TAX_CISCO_USD_AMT as FINANCED_TAX_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.TRAINING_TAX_CISCO_LC_AMT as TRAINING_TAX_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.TRAINING_TAX_CISCO_USD_AMT as TRAINING_TAX_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.WEBEX_SERVICES_CISCO_LC_AMT as WEBEX_SERVICES_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.WEBEX_SERVICES_CISCO_USD_AMT as WEBEX_SERVICES_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.PROF_SERVICES_CISCO_LC_AMT as PROF_SERVICES_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.PROF_SERVICES_CISCO_USD_AMT as PROF_SERVICES_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.SERVICES_CISCO_LC_AMT as SERVICES_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.SERVICES_CISCO_USD_AMT as SERVICES_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.CONSULTING_NON_CISCO_LC_AMT as CONSULTING_NON_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.CONSULTING_NON_CISCO_USD_AMT as CONSULTING_NON_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.FINANCED_TAX_NON_CISCO_LC_AMT as FINANCED_TAX_NON_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.FINANCED_TAX_NON_CISCO_USD_AMT as FINANCED_TAX_NON_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.TRAINING_NON_CISCO_LC_AMT as TRAINING_NON_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.TRAINING_NON_CISCO_USD_AMT as TRAINING_NON_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.PROF_SERVICE_NON_CISCO_LC_AMT as PROF_SERVICE_NON_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.PROF_SERVICE_NON_CISCO_USD_AMT as PROF_SERVICE_NON_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.SERVICES_NON_CISCO_LC_AMT as SERVICES_NON_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.SERVICES_NON_CISCO_USD_AMT as SERVICES_NON_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.SOFTWARE_CISCO_LC_AMT as SOFTWARE_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.SOFTWARE_CISCO_USD_AMT as SOFTWARE_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.SOFTWARE_NON_CISCO_LC_AMT as SOFTWARE_NON_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.SOFTWARE_NON_CISCO_USD_AMT as SOFTWARE_NON_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.MAINTENANCE_NON_CISCO_LC_AMT as MAINTENANCE_NON_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.MAINTENANCE_NON_CISCO_USD_AMT as MAINTENANCE_NON_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.MAINT_HARDWARE_CISCO_LC_AMT as MAINT_HARDWARE_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.MAINT_HARDWARE_CISCO_USD_AMT as MAINT_HARDWARE_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.MAINT_SOFTWARE_CISCO_LC_AMT as MAINT_SOFTWARE_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.MAINT_SOFTWARE_CISCO_USD_AMT as MAINT_SOFTWARE_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.MAINT_SMARTNET_CISCO_LC_AMT as MAINT_SMARTNET_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.MAINT_SMARTNET_CISCO_USD_AMT as MAINT_SMARTNET_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.MAINT_PHONE_SUP_CISCO_LC_AMT as MAINT_PHONE_SUP_CISCO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.MAINT_PHONE_SUP_CISCO_USD_AMT as MAINT_PHONE_SUP_CISCO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.FINANCED_FEE_LC_AMT as FINANCED_FEE_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.FINANCED_FEE_USD_AMT as FINANCED_FEE_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.BOOK_LC_AMT as BOOK_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.BOOK_USD_AMT as BOOK_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.GROSS_PO_LC_AMT as GROSS_PO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.GROSS_PO_USD_AMT as GROSS_PO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.NET_PO_LC_AMT as NET_PO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.NET_PO_USD_AMT as NET_PO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.BLIND_DISCOUNT_LC_AMT as BLIND_DISCOUNT_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.BLIND_DISCOUNT_USD_AMT as BLIND_DISCOUNT_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.HARDWARE_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as HARDWARE_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.HARDWARE_CISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as HARDWARE_CISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.HARDWARE_NONCISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as HARDWARE_NONCISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.HARDWARE_NONCSCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as HARDWARE_NONCSCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.SW_ESSNTL_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as SW_ESSNTL_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.SW_ESSNTL_CISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as SW_ESSNTL_CISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.FREIGHT_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as FREIGHT_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.FREIGHT_CISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as FREIGHT_CISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.FREIGHT_NONCISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as FREIGHT_NONCISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.FREIGHT_NONCISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as FREIGHT_NONCISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.INSTALL_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as INSTALL_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.INSTALL_CISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as INSTALL_CISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.INSTALL_NON_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as INSTALL_NON_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.INSTALL_NON_CSCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as INSTALL_NON_CSCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.CONSULTING_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as CONSULTING_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.CONSULTING_CISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as CONSULTING_CISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.FINANCE_TAX_CSCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as FINANCE_TAX_CSCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.FINANCE_TAX_CSCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as FINANCE_TAX_CSCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.TRAINING_TAX_CSCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as TRAINING_TAX_CSCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.TRAINING_TAX_CSCO_DLTA_USD_AMT as TRAINING_TAX_CSCO_DLTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.WEBEX_SVC_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as WEBEX_SVC_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.WEBEX_SVC_CISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as WEBEX_SVC_CISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.PROF_SVC_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as PROF_SVC_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.PROF_SVC_CISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as PROF_SVC_CISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.SERVICES_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as SERVICES_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.SERVICES_CISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as SERVICES_CISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.CONSULT_NONCISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as CONSULT_NONCISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.CONSULT_NONCISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as CONSULT_NONCISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.FIN_TAX_NONCISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as FIN_TAX_NONCISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.FIN_TAX_NONCISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as FIN_TAX_NONCISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.TRAINING_NONCISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as TRAINING_NONCISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.TRAINING_NONCSCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as TRAINING_NONCSCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.PROF_SVC_NONCISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as PROF_SVC_NONCISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.PROF_SVC_NONCSCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as PROF_SVC_NONCSCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.SERVICES_NONCISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as SERVICES_NONCISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.SERVICES_NONCSCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as SERVICES_NONCSCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.SOFTWARE_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as SOFTWARE_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.SOFTWARE_CISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as SOFTWARE_CISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.SOFTWARE_NONCISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as SOFTWARE_NONCISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.SOFTWARE_NONCSCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as SOFTWARE_NONCSCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.MAINT_NONCISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as MAINT_NONCISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.MAINT_NONCISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as MAINT_NONCISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.MAINT_HW_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as MAINT_HW_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.MAINT_HW_CISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as MAINT_HW_CISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.MAINT_SW_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as MAINT_SW_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.MAINT_SW_CISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as MAINT_SW_CISCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.MAINT_SMNET_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as MAINT_SMNET_CISCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.MAINT_SMNET_CSCO_DELTA_USD_AMT as MAINT_SMNET_CSCO_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.MAINT_PH_SUP_CSCO_DELTA_LC_AMT as MAINT_PH_SUP_CSCO_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.MAINT_PH_SUP_CSCO_DLTA_USD_AMT as MAINT_PH_SUP_CSCO_DLTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.FINANCED_FEE_DELTA_LC_AMT as FINANCED_FEE_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.FINANCED_FEE_DELTA_USD_AMT as FINANCED_FEE_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.BOOK_DELTA_LC_AMT as BOOK_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.BOOK_DELTA_USD_AMT as BOOK_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.GROSS_DELTA_PO_LC_AMT as GROSS_DELTA_PO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.GROSS_DELTA_PO_USD_AMT as GROSS_DELTA_PO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.NET_DELTA_PO_LC_AMT as NET_DELTA_PO_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.NET_DELTA_PO_USD_AMT as NET_DELTA_PO_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.BLIND_DISCOUNT_DELTA_LC_AMT as BLIND_DISCOUNT_DELTA_LC_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; CDL_BOOKINGS_F.BLIND_DISCOUNT_DELTA_USD_AMT as BLIND_DISCOUNT_DELTA_USD_AMT,&#xD;&#xA; MAX_VALUE.ORDER_CNT as  ORDER_CNT,&#xD;&#xA; MAX_VALUE.PURCHASE_ORDER_NUM AS PURCHASE_ORDER_NUM&#xD;&#xA; FROM CDL_BOOKINGS_F,&#xD;&#xA; (SELECT MAX(BOOKINGS_FACT_KEY) BOOKINGS_FACT_KEY ,count(*) ORDER_CNT,PURCHASE_ORDER_NUM &#xD;&#xA;FROM CDL_BOOKINGS_F ,CDL_PURCHASE_ORDER_D&#xD;&#xA;WHERE CDL_BOOKINGS_F.PURCHASE_ORDER_KEY = CDL_PURCHASE_ORDER_D.PURCHASE_ORDER_KEY&#xD;&#xA;GROUP BY PURCHASE_ORDER_NUM) MAX_VALUE&#xD;&#xA; WHERE &#xD;&#xA;CDL_BOOKINGS_F.BOOKINGS_FACT_KEY = MAX_VALUE.BOOKINGS_FACT_KEY"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup table name" VALUE ="CDL_BOOKINGS_F"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup Source Filter" VALUE =""/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup caching enabled" VALUE ="YES"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup policy on multiple match" VALUE ="Use Any Value"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup condition" VALUE ="PURCHASE_ORDER_NUM = I_PURCHASE_ORDER_NUM"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Connection Information" VALUE ="$Target"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Source Type" VALUE ="Database"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Recache if Stale" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Tracing Level" VALUE ="Normal"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup cache directory name" VALUE ="$PMCacheDir"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup cache initialize" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup cache persistent" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup Data Cache Size" VALUE ="Auto"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup Index Cache Size" VALUE ="Auto"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Dynamic Lookup Cache" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Synchronize Dynamic Cache" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Output Old Value On Update" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Update Dynamic Cache Condition" VALUE ="TRUE"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Cache File Name Prefix" VALUE =""/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Re-cache from lookup source" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Insert Else Update" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Update Else Insert" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Datetime Format" VALUE =""/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Thousand Separator" VALUE ="None"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Decimal Separator" VALUE ="."/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Case Sensitive String Comparison" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Null ordering" VALUE ="Null Is Highest Value"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Sorted Input" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup source is static" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Pre-build lookup cache" VALUE ="Auto"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Subsecond Precision" VALUE ="6"/>
</TRANSFORMATION>
<TRANSFORMATION DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="Lkp_CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO" OBJECTVERSION ="1" REUSABLE ="NO" TYPE ="Lookup Procedure" VERSIONNUMBER ="4">
    <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="decimal" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="ORIG_PO_HEADER_KEY" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="LOOKUP/OUTPUT" PRECISION ="38" SCALE ="0"/>
    <!-- ="0"/> -->
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup Sql Override" VALUE ="SELECT &#xD;&#xA;CIL_ORIG_PO_HEADER.ORIG_PO_HEADER_KEY AS  ORIG_PO_HEADER_KEY,&#xD;&#xA;DECODE (SUM( CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.CUST_FINANCED_LC_AMT),0, 0,&#xD;&#xA;SUM(CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.CSC_YIELD_PCT * CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.CUST_FINANCED_LC_AMT)/ SUM( CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.CUST_FINANCED_LC_AMT))&#xD;&#xA;AS CAPITAL_INTEREST_RT,&#xD;&#xA;DECODE (SUM( CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.CUST_FINANCED_LC_AMT),0, 0,&#xD;&#xA;SUM(CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.CUST_YIELD_PCT * CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.CUST_FINANCED_LC_AMT)/ SUM( CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.CUST_FINANCED_LC_AMT)) AS CUSTOMER_INTREST_RT,&#xD;&#xA;DECODE (SUM( CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.CUST_FINANCED_LC_AMT),0, 0,&#xD;&#xA;SUM(CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.CSC_NPV_PCT* CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.CUST_FINANCED_LC_AMT)/ SUM( CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.CUST_FINANCED_LC_AMT)) AS  NPV_PCT,&#xD;&#xA;DECODE (SUM( CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.CUST_FINANCED_LC_AMT),0, 0&#xD;&#xA;,SUM(CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.RV_PCT * CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.CUST_FINANCED_LC_AMT)/ SUM( CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.CUST_FINANCED_LC_AMT)) AS RESIDUAL_VALUE_PCT&#xD;&#xA;FROM CILNL.CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO,CILNL.CIL_ORIG_PO_HEADER,CILNL.CIL_ORIG_PO_LINE,CILNL.CIL_ORIG_QUOTE_LINE&#xD;&#xA;WHERE &#xD;&#xA;CIL_ORIG_PO_HEADER.ORIG_PO_HEADER_KEY=CIL_ORIG_PO_LINE .ORIG_PO_HEADER_KEY  &#xD;&#xA;AND CIL_ORIG_PO_LINE.ORIG_QUOTE_LINE_KEY =CIL_ORIG_QUOTE_LINE.ORIG_QUOTE_LINE_KEY&#xD;&#xA;AND CIL_ORIG_QUOTE_LINE.ORIG_BOM_HEADER_KEY = CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.ORIG_BOM_HEADER_KEY&#xD;&#xA;GROUP BY CIL_ORIG_PO_HEADER.ORIG_PO_HEADER_KEY"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup table name" VALUE ="CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup Source Filter" VALUE =""/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup caching enabled" VALUE ="YES"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup policy on multiple match" VALUE ="Use Any Value"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup condition" VALUE ="ORIG_PO_HEADER_KEY = CIL_PURCHASE_ORDER_KEY"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Connection Information" VALUE ="$Target"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Source Type" VALUE ="Database"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Recache if Stale" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Tracing Level" VALUE ="Normal"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup cache directory name" VALUE ="$PMCacheDir"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup cache initialize" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup cache persistent" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup Data Cache Size" VALUE ="Auto"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup Index Cache Size" VALUE ="Auto"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Dynamic Lookup Cache" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Synchronize Dynamic Cache" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Output Old Value On Update" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Update Dynamic Cache Condition" VALUE ="TRUE"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Cache File Name Prefix" VALUE =""/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Re-cache from lookup source" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Insert Else Update" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Update Else Insert" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Datetime Format" VALUE =""/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Thousand Separator" VALUE ="None"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Decimal Separator" VALUE ="."/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Case Sensitive String Comparison" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Null ordering" VALUE ="Null Is Highest Value"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Sorted Input" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup source is static" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Pre-build lookup cache" VALUE ="Auto"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Subsecond Precision" VALUE ="6"/>
</TRANSFORMATION>
<TRANSFORMATION DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="Lkp_EQIP_MAINT_PCT" OBJECTVERSION ="1" REUSABLE ="NO" TYPE ="Lookup Procedure" VERSIONNUMBER ="3">
    <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="decimal" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="SUMM" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="LOOKUP/RETURN/OUTPUT" PRECISION ="26" SCALE ="7"/>
    <!-- SCALE ="0"/> -->
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup Sql Override" VALUE ="SELECT &#xD;&#xA;DECODE(sum( CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.CSC_FINANCED_LC_AMT),0,0, sum(CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.CSC_YIELD_PCT * CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.CSC_FINANCED_LC_AMT)/sum( CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.CSC_FINANCED_LC_AMT)) AS SUMM,&#xD;&#xA;CIL_ORIG_PO_LINE.ORIG_PO_HEADER_KEY AS ORIG_PO_HEADER_KEY,&#xD;&#xA;CIL_ORIG_PRCNG_SCENARIO_GROUP.AK_PRICING_GROUP_TYPE_CD AS AK_PRICING_GROUP_TYPE_CD&#xD;&#xA;FROM &#xD;&#xA;CILNL.CIL_ORIG_PO_LINE,CILNL.CIL_ORIG_QUOTE_LINE,CILNL.CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO,CILNL.CIL_ORIG_PRCNG_SCENARIO_GROUP,&#xD;&#xA;CILNL.CIL_ORIG_PO_HEADER&#xD;&#xA;WHERE &#xD;&#xA;CIL_ORIG_PO_HEADER .ORIG_PO_HEADER_KEY=CIL_ORIG_PO_LINE .ORIG_PO_HEADER_KEY&#xD;&#xA;AND CIL_ORIG_PO_LINE.ORIG_QUOTE_LINE_KEY =CIL_ORIG_QUOTE_LINE.ORIG_QUOTE_LINE_KEY&#xD;&#xA;AND CIL_ORIG_QUOTE_LINE.ORIG_BOM_HEADER_KEY = CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.ORIG_BOM_HEADER_KEY&#xD;&#xA;AND CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO.ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO_KEY=CIL_ORIG_PRCNG_SCENARIO_GROUP.AK_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO_KEY&#xD;&#xA;GROUP BY CIL_ORIG_PO_LINE .ORIG_PO_HEADER_KEY,CIL_ORIG_PRCNG_SCENARIO_GROUP.AK_PRICING_GROUP_TYPE_CD"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup table name" VALUE ="CIL_ORIG_PRICING_SCENARIO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup Source Filter" VALUE =""/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup caching enabled" VALUE ="YES"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup policy on multiple match" VALUE ="Use Any Value"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup condition" VALUE ="ORIG_PO_HEADER_KEY = IN_CIL_PURCHASE_ORDER_KEY AND AK_PRICING_GROUP_TYPE_CD = IN_AK_PRICING_GROUP_TYPE_CD"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Connection Information" VALUE ="$Target"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Source Type" VALUE ="Database"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Recache if Stale" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Tracing Level" VALUE ="Normal"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup cache directory name" VALUE ="$PMCacheDir"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup cache initialize" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup cache persistent" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup Data Cache Size" VALUE ="Auto"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup Index Cache Size" VALUE ="Auto"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Dynamic Lookup Cache" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Synchronize Dynamic Cache" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Output Old Value On Update" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Update Dynamic Cache Condition" VALUE ="TRUE"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Cache File Name Prefix" VALUE =""/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Re-cache from lookup source" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Insert Else Update" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Update Else Insert" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Datetime Format" VALUE =""/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Thousand Separator" VALUE ="None"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Decimal Separator" VALUE ="."/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Case Sensitive String Comparison" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Null ordering" VALUE ="Null Is Highest Value"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Sorted Input" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Lookup source is static" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Pre-build lookup cache" VALUE ="Auto"/>
    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Subsecond Precision" VALUE ="6"/>
```

Can you please help me in this?

Comment: Can you list an example input and output file?

Comment: where can i attach those files

Comment: Shorten them down to a minimal example and add them directly to the question.

Comment: Just post representative samples. Complete files are not required.

Comment: added the main XML file and LOTO.txt is the file from where the list tranformation are present

Comment: issue is that for one Lkp i getting the correct Select query     but im getting the same select query for the remaining LKP's even

Comment: You are asking a question about the construction of the SQL variable, but you don't provide anything from the testingfull.txt input file -- presumably that's where you expect to see the source of the different SQL statements being derived?

Comment: So, is that sample input? Or sample output?

Comment: XML is testingfull.txt that is the file from which i will extract the details

Comment: actually from the testingfull.txt file i will extract the details of each transfomation like for example  "Lkp_something SQL is select A" and Lkp_ofsomeother is select B  but here for all the LKP_  im geting select A

Comment: ok, but there is no meaningful content in the XML you've posted -- no match possible for the first sed, so it's not possible to parse the rest of the piped commands

Comment: 1 word from the file LOTO.txt is "Lkp_CDL_BOOKINGS_F_Delta_AMT" here im taking the 3 charaters Lkp and checking in the if condition then it go to the valid if and from then sed will working on the XML file by checking for the word "Lkp_CDL_BOOKINGS_F_Delta_AMT" and extract SELECT statements

Comment: yes, but the first sed matches from there to EOF -- the grep fails, so the input to the rest of the chain is nil

Comment: sed -n '/$T/,/VALUE ="Never"/p'                                     the above se will picks data which starts from $T which is nothing but "Lkp_CDL_BOOKINGS_F_Delta_AMT" till the pattern VALUE ="Never"   after this grep will start will extract select from the resultant of the above --- jstevenco hi it is able to pick select of one LKP :)

Comment: sorry -- i confused you -- when I say "first sed" i mean the one you care about in your question -- the one that amounts to sed -n '/Lkp/,/VALUE ="Null Is Highest Value"/p' -- you have no valid match for VALUE ="Null"... etc in you example input

Comment: <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Null ordering" VALUE ="Null Is Highest Value"/>     copy the xml and paste it outside in that you will find

Comment: You need to start over and discard that shell script as it is riddled with issues. Post a SMALL sample of both LOTO.txt and testingfull.txt along with the output you would currently get from your script given those input files. Given that we can help you re-write your script to be more readable, maintainable, etc. and THEN we can help you enhance it for the new functionality you're looking for.

Comment: ok i will post sample inout files and sample output which i got from my script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around with this a bit.  I could get the core logic to work on the command line but not in the context of the script -- I'm thinking that shell metacharacter interpretation lies at the heart of it.  I tweaked the script a bit to get it to work -- at least for the `Lkp` cases.  You'll need to verify for the `SQ_` cases.  The revised script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read T
do
    {
    TYPE=`echo $T | cut -c-4 | cut -c2-`
    TARGET=`echo $T | sed 's/"//g'`
    echo "Type = $TYPE"
    if [ "$TYPE" = "SQ_" ];  then
        cmd="cat testingfull.txt | sed -n '/$TARGET/,/VALUE =\"Never\"/p'| grep \"Sql Query\" | sed  's/&#xD;&#xA;//g'| sed 's/&apos;Y&apos;//g' | cut -d '\"' -f 4"
        SQL=`eval $cmd`
        echo "$T     : $SQL"$'\n' >> singletesting.txt
    elif [ "$TYPE" = "GET" ];  then
        SQL='GET_MAX_VALUE               :           Reusable transformation to get the max key value from the target Table'
        echo "$SQL"$'\n' >> singletesting.txt
    elif [ "$TYPE" = "Lkp" ];  then
        cmd="cat testingfull.txt | sed -n '/$TARGET/,/VALUE =\"Null Is Highest Value\"/p' | grep 'Lookup Sql Override' | sed  's/&#xD;&#xA;//g'| sed 's/&apos;Y&apos;//g' | cut -d '\"' -f 4"
        SQL=`eval $cmd`
        echo "$T     : $SQL"$'\n' >> singletesting.txt
    else
        echo "$T           :   under construction"$'\n'$'\n' >> singletesting.txt
    fi
    }
done < LOTO.txt
```

Comment: hi jstevenco   i got the issue resolved in your code            cmd="cat testingfull.txt | sed -n '/$TARGET/--- here we need to keep this  /'"$TARGET"'/